# Close with escape key ajax ModalPopupExtender not working

Tags: asp.net, ajax, modalpopupextender

I'm using the following code to close a modalPopup but for some reason is not working.

```
<script>
     function pageLoad(sender, args){
      if(!args.get_isPartialLoad()){
        //  add our handler to the document's
        //  keydown event
         $addHandler(document, "keydown", onKeyDown);
       }
  }

function onKeyDown(e){
if(e && e.keyCode == Sys.UI.Key.esc){
    // if the key pressed is the escape key, dismiss the dialog
    $find('ModalPopupExtenderPanelFullViewProductos').hide();
     }
   } 
 </script>

<ajax:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtenderPanelFullViewProductos"
                         runat="server" TargetControlID="LinkButtonDummy"  
                         BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" 
                         PopupControlID="PanelFullViewProductos"
                         X="20" Y="50" DropShadow="true" 
                         RepositionMode="None">
 </ajax:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set a BehaviorID for your modal popup extender..Then you can use

```
$find('BehaviorID').hide();
```

Please Mark as answer if it satisfies you..